# Codeigniter active record doesn't run Queries containing Unicodes properly

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord, unicode

I want to run a query that says:

> SELECT * FROM (`restaurants`) WHERE `restaurant_name` LIKE
>   'دالون'

I've used active record to make this query, but the result is

> SELECT * FROM (`restaurants`) WHERE `restaurant_name` LIKE
>   '%\%D8\%AF\%D8\%A7\%D9\%84\%D9\%88\%D9\%86%'

and database doesn't return a result.

My first Q is that what is this change called?

and What to do to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your character encoding in `config.php` is as follows:

```
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
```

Also, you probably want to change your database configs to match the following:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_unicode_ci";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've used these settings, but no luck.